# Cherrypy application redirecting to http instead of https behind nginx

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy webapp that I host behind an nginx reverse-proxy with ssl.

The nginx location is set up as such:

```
    location /webapp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8642;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Everything works when I load up https://myaddress.com/webapp. The page loads fine.

But when I click on any links, it opens http://myaddress.com/webapp/page, which doesn't load when behind nginx with ssl.

The links are a simple

```
<a href='/webapp/page'>Page</a>
```

I can then manually open https://myaddress.com/webapp/page which loads fine.

I can't figure out why the browser is kicking it over to http:// instead of staying on https://

EDIT:

I figured this out (kind of) a while ago and forgot about this post.

Changing the main method name from index() to default() fixed this. I can't figure out why, and I can't find anything in the CherryPy docs for it.

So when going to mysite.com/news Cherrypy now returns News.default() instead of News.index() and this doesn't change the URI.

Comment: Have you checked that `<a href='/webapp/page'>Page</a>` really gets into the browser as is? Do you have any JS click handlers, which might alter this behaviour? What is the browser you use?

Comment: This happens on Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tested others. 


There is no javascript handling the links.


I have found that changing the method name in cherrypy from index() to default() doesn't change the target to http, but when I execute a HTTPRedirect() it sends it to http:// instead of https://

Comment: Oh.. I see. The issue is that cherrypy is listening to http and does not know anything about nginx. If you use relative URI when raising `HTTPRedirect` it tries to construct a complete URL with scheme using information available. Alternatively you could generate an absolute URL yourself using `cherrypy.url()` function.

Comment: cherrypy.url() does not return the *actual* request.


For example, I go to `https://example.com/myapp` which simple fires `return cherrypy.url()` which outputs `http://example.com/myapp`

Comment: you should pass base argument

Comment: Pass it to what? That isn't terribly descriptive.

Comment: `return cherrypy.url(base='https://example.com')`

Comment: The problem is that this is a user-hosted application, so I can't know if they are using https via nginx or not.

Comment: Try following @cyraxjoe's advice and enable `cherrypy.tools.proxy` tool

Answer (score 3):

Are you enabling the reverse proxy tool?

You can do so by adding into your config file:

`tool.proxy.on = True`

or by decorating.

`@cherrypy.tools.proxy`

Part of the functionality of that tool is to adjust the application base by adjusting the protocol from `http` to `https`.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help. Needs testing. It didn't provide me with correct FQDN in the past.